# Install4j compilation fails with "Password seems to be wrong"

Tags: install4j

What causes `install4j: compilation failed. Reason: Password seems to be wrong. (Windows)`, and how do I fix it?
Using install4j-maven-plugin:1.1.1 with install4j 7.0.6.

```
18:06:19  [INFO] --- install4j-maven-plugin:1.1.1:install-license (install-license) @ id-gui ---
18:06:21  [INFO] Updated licensing information.
18:06:21  [INFO] 
18:06:21  [INFO] --- install4j-maven-plugin:1.1.1:compile (compile-installers) @ id-gui ---
18:06:23  [INFO] install4j version 7.0.6 (build 7181), built on 2018-06-11
18:06:23  [INFO] Using Java 1.8.0_242 from /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre
18:06:23  [INFO] Registered to 
18:06:23  [INFO] 
18:06:23  [INFO] Loading config file /var/jenkins_home/workspace/eature_jo-migrate-jenkins-server/src/install/six-id.install4j
18:06:24  [INFO] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: Password seems to be wrong. (Windows)
18:06:25  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:06:25  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
18:06:25  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:06:25  [INFO] Total time:  26.536 s
18:06:25  [INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-08T16:06:25Z
18:06:25  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:06:25  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.1.1:compile (compile-installers) on project id-gui: null returned: 1 -> [Help 1]
18:06:25  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.1.1:compile (compile-installers) on project id-gui: null returned: 1
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:06:25      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:06:25      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
18:06:25  Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: null returned: 1
18:06:25      at org.sonatype.install4j.maven.MojoSupport.execute (MojoSupport.java:44)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:06:25      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:06:25      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
18:06:25  Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: null returned: 1
18:06:25      at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute (ExecTask.java:646)
18:06:25      at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec (ExecTask.java:672)
18:06:25      at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute (ExecTask.java:498)
18:06:25      at org.sonatype.install4j.maven.CompileMojo.execute (CompileMojo.java:270)
18:06:25      at org.sonatype.install4j.maven.Install4jcMojoSupport.doExecute (Install4jcMojoSupport.java:96)
18:06:25      at org.sonatype.install4j.maven.MojoSupport.execute (MojoSupport.java:35)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:06:25      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
18:06:25      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
18:06:25      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:06:25      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
18:06:25      at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message comes from Windows code signing and refers to the password of your code signing certificate.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the message happens on a Linux system. (The build on Windows actually works.)

Comment: Ah right. The builds are set up differently between the two systems, it's possible that the settings.xml file that provides the password varies.

Comment: Yep, that nailed it, message is gone. (Back to the usual firewall complications during countersigning *sigh*.)

Comment: Suggestion: Mention the options's name (winKeystorePassword) in the message so people know what was being done using what data. Something like "Error signing the Windows executable, possible causes: winKeystorePassword is wrong, ...".

Comment: You are right, this will be improved in 8.0.8. Thanks for your feedback.